# How to pass datetime as parameter to a sql openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, openquery

I have an `OPENQUERY` statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (NETLINE, 
                'SELECT * FROM XCREW.CTNAISV_HOTELCREW where RESERVATION_DATE = ''2015-05-01''')
```

After executing it I have error message on 2015

How to pass datetime as parameter in `OPENQUERY` ?

Thanks

Comment: SQL-Server, just clear for openquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead. Explicitly convert it to a datetime (maybe convert it to the proper datetime format you use).

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (NETLINE, 
                'SELECT * FROM XCREW.CTNAISV_HOTELCREW where RESERVATION_DATE = CONVERT(datetime,''2015-05-01'')')
```

The proper format can also applied using `CONVERT(datetime, N'2015-05-01', 112)` (for example).

Answer (score 0):

quotes were wrong. This query execute correctly

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY (NETLINE,
  'SELECT *
  FROM XCREW.CTNAISV_HOTELCREW
  WHERE RESERVATION_DATE BETWEEN ''01-01-2015'' AND ''05-05-2015'''
)
```

and also date format was wrong